# R library package devtools fails on RCurl error

Tags: linux, r, ubuntu, curl

Currently using Ububtu 14.04 with R 3.0 and RStudio. The installation of devtools failed on the installation of the curl package. I had successfully installed Rcpp by a restart previously - So I tried a clean start of R and Rstudio and tried installing package curl first - with the error messages below:

```
install.packages("curl")
Installing package into ‘/home/freya/R/i686-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/curl_0.9.2.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 244688 bytes (238 Kb)
opened URL
==================================================
downloaded 238 Kb

* installing *source* package ‘curl’ ...
** package ‘curl’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
File curl.h not found. Make sure the curl development library is installed, e.g. libcurl4-openssl-dev (deb) or libcurl-devel (rpm).
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘curl’
* removing ‘/home/freya/R/i686-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0/curl’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘curl’ had non-zero exit status
```

Any suggestions appreciated, Thanks

KNB

Comment: `sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev`?

Comment: @knban1 how did you finally resolve it?